# Vendor Prefix css3 properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying add animation-duration css3 property respective of height and width of grid. I made it using this code **div.style.animationDuration**. It works good for me.

my concern is how to add vendor prefix css3 property for animation-duration in js like -ms-animation-duration

Comment: Latest browser version require no prefix except Safari with `-webkit`. I don't think MS ever prefixed this.

Answer (score 1):

Generally vendor prefixes in javascript for css are as follows:

1. moz for Mozilla Firefox
2. webkit for Google Chrome , Apple Safari, and
   other webkit-based browsers
3. ms for Microsoft Internet Explorer
4. o for Opera

   Hence you can replace `div.style.animationDuration` with `div.style.webkitAnimationDuration`

To deal with this problem in general you can write a method

```
function setVendorCss(element, property, value) {
  element.style["webkit" + property] = value;
  element.style["moz" + property] = value;
  element.style["ms" + property] = value;
  element.style["o" + property] = value;
}
```

Read more here https://www.kirupa.com/html5/vendor_prefixes_javascript.htm

Comment: Shouldn't it be `webkitAnimationDuration` with an upper-case "A"?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting the element like so:

```
element.style.color = 'red';
element.style.fontSize = '2em';
```

Try:

```
element.style.cssText = 'color: red; font-size: 2em';
```

style.cssText is useful for adding multiple styles at a time, even the trickier ones that require prefixes.